# By clicking on image in image view image download from app and save in internal storage

Tags: android

I download an image from server and set it on image view. It works correctly but now I want to save this image to internal storage by click on image view. Is there any solution for it.
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a library to download your images or you store them first then read and set to imageView?

Comment: using picaso library. it works correctly. but now i want to store it in internal storage

Comment: I have not dug deeper into how picasso works with storage but perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to download the selected image using a background thread then store it separately. You should know ahead of time the file name of your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create onClick listener on your ImageView and call to method to download the image. You can use this example to for download and save the image:

```
   OutputStream fOut = null;
    try {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File file = new File(path, "myCollage.jpg"); // the File to save to
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream

        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());


    }catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you bring some code, like the instantiation of the ImageView? Would make it easier for everyone to help you.

Because it's from scratch, i'll give you a generic element of response.
Assuming you have instantiated your ImageView as *mImageView*:

```
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //Put in internal storage
            }
        });
```

And don't forget to set the following, in your image layout (XML file):

```
android:clickable="true"
```

For the storage part, i won't explain better than what's already here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://192.168.43.61/CustomerEntrySys/"+imagepath+"").into(iv); i get image from wamp server by using this.

Comment: Okay, can you try what i told you? the storage part if you've successfully loaded the extern image in your object.

Comment: i am new in android. i do not understand.

Comment: Have you read the internal storage part? I will edit my answer if you really don't understand but it shoudln't be hard, just replace the string in the example given by your ImageView :)

Comment: mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //Put in internal storage
            }
        }); what code have to write in this method

Comment: Just combine my answer and what Eliran Tutia proposed below